# Resize an image after cropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop, image-resizing

Folks,I am working on an image component for my application and it involves image cropping and resizing.
The issue we are facing is we are able to crop the image keeping the aspect ratio constant initially,but in our case the user can again resize the cropped image and here comes the problem.If we try to resize the cropped image we also get the portion of the image which is not present in the cropping area.
For reference I add this [link](http://app.imcreator.com/edit).We want to have a somewhat similar functionality.But the problem is we are not able to get the **logic right**.Once we crop a portion we get the `height`,`width` of that image.We have the original `aspect ratio`,but how can we now calculate the images new height,width when theuser resizes the cropped portion?
The actual image is present and we do not crop it **actually**,but **virtually** for showing it to the user.We are using **javascript/jquery** for achieving this.No specific library but just the logic of **aspect ratio** till now
This is the actual picture.

[image]

**This is the cropping area selected.And this would be the cropped area.**

[image]

This is the resized image after cropping.The image resizes only for the cropped portion and not the entire one,whereas its actually present there.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. Are you saying that the user can, for example, choose a square portion from a rectangular image then resize it further maintaining square ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Just from playing with your application the error that is generated would be similar to an error that would be created if you asked for a CSS property with Jquery after selecting multiple elements. A function can only return a singl result, so you still only obtain the property for the first matched element. Although I can not be sure because your code is 8000 lines long with no comments

Comment: Well the link added isn't my site.I added it for reference.We are trying to achieve something similar.Its not my code.The reason I haven;t added any code is,we are stuck more logically then syntactically.We are confused how exactly we can go about the problem!

Comment: OHH so let me get this clear. The Users crops the pictures. that's fine. Then the user resizes the picture, and your goal is to get the dimensions of that picture?

Comment: Yes actually I am stuck at a point after cropping how to get the dimensions + the position of the image i.e `left`,`top` and then call the same resize function that I would normally.Now what happens is,if I resize I also get the part of the image which was not in the crop portion.

Comment: If you have a look at the 2nd image the original image is still present at the back,its just hidden for the user,so when I resize the cropped portion the actual image resizes too.

Comment: are you trying to keep the original image?

Comment: No later it won't be there,but while the user is editing it would be present.Once he publishes the template it would be removed.